# How to check if this function is semicontinuous

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

Could you tell me how to check that this functions are semicontinuous?

$(X, \tau)$ - topological space, $ \ X \neq \emptyset$, $ \ f: X \rightarrow \bar{\mathbb{R}}$, $ \ \bar{\mathbb{R}} = [- \infty, + \infty]$, $ \ \ x \in X$,

$ M_f(x) = \inf \{\sup f(U) \ | \ U  \ \ \text{is a neighbourhood of x}\}$

$m_f(x) = \sup \{\inf f(U) \ | \ U  \ \ \text{is a neighbourhood of x}\}$

$M_f, m_f : X \rightarrow \bar{\mathbb{R}}$

I've read that $\sup$ and $\inf$ are resp. lower and upper semicontinuous.
So I need to show that $\{x \in X \ | \ M_f(x) < a\} \in \tau$ and $\{x \in X \ | \ m_f(x) > a\} \in \tau$ for $a \in \mathbb{R}$, but I don't know how to show this. Could you help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think these are called the lower and upper semicontinuous regularizations of $f$.

When is $M_f(x)<a$? When there is a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $\sup f(U)<a$. But then $M_f(y)<a$ for all $y\in U$, because $U$ is also a neighborhood of $y$. Thus, the set $\{x: M_f(x)<a\}$  is open.

When is $m_f(x)>a$? When there is a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $\inf f(U)>a$. But then $m_f(y)>a$ for all $y\in U$, because $U$ is also a neighborhood of $y$. Thus, the set $\{x: m_f(x)>a\}$  is open.

Comment: So these sets are open because they contain a neighbourhood of each of their points. Is that right?

Comment: Ok. Thank you a lot for your help!